Move_group not publishing to /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
I'm basically trying to connect my robot (meca 500) and simulate it both in gazebo and rviz. I was able to achieve this using Moveit Setup Assistant. However when I try to move my robot in rviz, my planning calculates the solutions but fails when I execute it.
[ INFO] [1718895627.912964400, 54.467000000]: Execution request received
[ INFO] [1718895627.913378500, 54.467000000]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ERROR] [1718895627.913628700, 54.467000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ meca_joint_1 meca_joint_2 meca_joint_3 meca_joint_4 meca_joint_5 meca_joint_6 ]
[ERROR] [1718895627.913843800, 54.467000000]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ INFO] [1718895627.941853100, 54.495000000]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution

I also went through many blog posts and checked if my controllers.yaml and controllers.launch are correct and as far as I know they seem to be okay.
controllers.yaml
# Simulation settings for using moveit_sim_controllers
moveit_sim_hw_interface:
  joint_model_group: meca_arm
  joint_model_group_pose: home
# Settings for ros_control_boilerplate control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01
# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - meca_joint_1
    - meca_joint_2
    - meca_joint_3
    - meca_joint_4
    - meca_joint_5
    - meca_joint_6
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity

# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
  
controller_list:
  -name: vel_controller
  action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
  type: FollowJointTrajectory
  default: true
  joints:
    - meca_joint_1
    - meca_joint_2
    - meca_joint_3
    - meca_joint_4
    - meca_joint_5
    - meca_joint_6

vel_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - meca_joint_1
    - meca_joint_2
    - meca_joint_3
    - meca_joint_4
    - meca_joint_5
    - meca_joint_6

controllers.launch
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
 <!-- probably not used  called from gazebo-->
 <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
 <rosparam file="$(find meca_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

 <!-- Load the controllers -->
 <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
   output="screen"  args="joint_state_controller vel_controller"/>
 
 <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
   <remap from="/joint_states" to="/meca_500_r3/joint_states" />
 </node>

</launch>

I also did rostopic list to check for /vel_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal and see if move_group is a publisher but apparently it's not.
I cloned another repo and checked rqt_graph and could see the controllers being connected to move_group which doesn't happen in my case.
I mean I understand where things are going south but I could't actually solve it. This community is my last resort. Please ask me if you require additional information and apologies if I'm asking a really stupid question since this is my first attempt with move_group.

I also checked with rqt_controller_manager and my controllers are initialised. I missed this info in my question
